# Retrieve required string from bigger JSON string

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have JSON string returned by method:

```
public List<Issues> Getdata(
        string jql,
        List<string> fields = null,
        int startAt = 0,
        int maxResult = 500)
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        string result = runQuery(JiraResource.search, data, "POST"); //returns results and working fine
        SearchResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResponse>(result);
        return response.IssueDescriptions = GetIssues(response);;
    }
```

and JSON string look like this:

```
{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":139,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"20930","self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/20930","key":"-139","fields":{"summary":"Rebate","issuetype":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1","id":"1","description":"A fee negotiation or quote","iconUrl":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/images/icons/issuetypes/sales.png","name":"Fees","subtask":false},"components":[],"created":"2015-07-10T12:29:05.000+1000","description":"Execute as per attached instruction","project":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/10013","id":"10013","key":"--","name":"Change Instructions","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10011","24x24":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10011","16x16":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10011","32x32":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10011"}},"reporter":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=rajap","name":"rajap","key":"rajap","emailAddress":"email.au","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10142","24x24":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10142","16x16":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10142","32x32":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10142"},"displayName":"Prabu","active":true,"timeZone":"US"},"priority":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3","iconUrl":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/major.png","name":"Medium","id":"3"},"resolution":null,"duedate":"2015-07-15","comment":{"startAt":0,"maxResults":1,"total":1,"comments":[{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/20930/comment/24290","id":"24290","author":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=acahill","name":"acahill","key":"acahill","emailAddress":"email","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10142","24x24":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10142","16x16":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10142","32x32":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10142"},"displayName":"Andrew Cahill","active":true,"timeZone":"US"},"body":"John, please action","updateAuthor":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=acahill","name":"acahill","key":"acahill","emailAddress":"email","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10142","24x24":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10142","16x16":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10142","32x32":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10142"},"displayName":"Andrew","active":true,"timeZone":"US"},"created":"2015-07-10T12:35:43.728+1000","updated":"2015-07-10T12:35:43.728+1000"}]},"votes":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/-139/votes","votes":0,"hasVoted":false},"assignee":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=olearyj","name":"olearyj","key":"olearyj","emailAddress":"email","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10142","24x24":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10142","16x16":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10142","32x32":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10142"},"displayName":"John","active":true,"timeZone":"US"},"status":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/1","description":"The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it.","iconUrl":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/open.png","name":"Open","id":"1","statusCategory":{"self":"https://clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2","id":2,"key":"new","colorName":"blue-gray","name":"To Do"}}}}]}
```

I wanted parser method for the above  json string to get particular values of these field values like :

"summary", "status", "assignee", 
                "comments", "description", "created", "duedate", "environment", "priority", "project", 
                "reporter", "resolution", "issuetype", "Updated", "votes", "components"

I tried to get one by one.however, its complex and time taking.

This is how I'm trying. But error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private List<JiraIssues> GetIssues(SearchResponse response)
{
    List<JiraIssues> returnResulttoReport = new List<JiraIssues>();
    foreach (var item in response.IssueDescriptions) //error here (not sure why IssueDescriptions is NULL but before call i'm de-serializing it)
    {
        foreach (var item1 in item.Comments)
        {

        }
    }

    return returnResulttoReport; 
}
```

My return type is `List<Issuees>`. Is there any library or example link to do this?

Please note that, I'm already de-serializing it, now I wanted perticular list from that.Also, please note that the JSON full string I have given is not same as the actual I have.But its similar. Please guide.

Comment: Well I'd use JsonConvert again, this time deserializing... or use LINQ to JSON. There are *lots* of resources about parsing JSON - what have you tried so far, and what was the problem? (It doesn't help that the *only* JSON array in your example is within GlossSeeAlso - GlossList really isn't a list...

Comment: Serialize this string to JSON, and use JSON.net to get values. See hint at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321513/parsing-json-returned-from-the-sitecore-item-web-api/31322580#31322580

Comment: plus the `json` posted is invalid.

Comment: I have updated my question, what I have tried. Also, I wanted to use Newtonsoft as I have already used that in some methods. If this is complex in newtonsoft, then I will choose another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate C# classes for the json, to prevent errors. Then do something like

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJsonString);
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example of how to get the summaries:

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

List<string> summaries = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in result.issues)
{
    var summary = item.fields.summary;
    Console.WriteLine(summary);
    summaries.Add(summary);
}
```

RootObject will represent the top level object of your JSON and then it will have properties which correspond to each of the properties of your JSON.

Comment: Here I wanted to get something which is very internal in the "result". How to fetch that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have "result.issues" = 150. So it will keep on going in foreach and return me the last. But, I want to get summary for each item.May be I have to return a list(becoz, I have to return so many things like summary).

Comment: Updated to show an example of adding them to a list

Comment: I'm trying to get, author name : "acahill" and displayName : "Andrew Cahill" from "Comments" like this "Console.WriteLine(item.fields.comment.comments.Comment2." However, getting error , it seems not recognizing Comment2. However, Comment2 is present in root class. Any suggession? Plaese edit you answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

```
    public class Issuetype
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string iconUrl { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool subtask { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvatarUrls
    {
        public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public AvatarUrls avatarUrls { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvatarUrls2
    {
        public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reporter
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public AvatarUrls2 avatarUrls { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Priority
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string iconUrl { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvatarUrls3
    {
        public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public AvatarUrls3 avatarUrls { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvatarUrls4
    {
        public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    }

    public class UpdateAuthor
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public AvatarUrls4 avatarUrls { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment2
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Author author { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public UpdateAuthor updateAuthor { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string updated { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public int startAt { get; set; }
        public int maxResults { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public List<Comment2> comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Votes
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public int votes { get; set; }
        public bool hasVoted { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvatarUrls5
    {
        public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Assignee
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public AvatarUrls5 avatarUrls { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class StatusCategory
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string colorName { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string iconUrl { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public StatusCategory statusCategory { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public Issuetype issuetype { get; set; }
        public List<object> components { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public Reporter reporter { get; set; }
        public Priority priority { get; set; }
        public object resolution { get; set; }
        public string duedate { get; set; }
        public Comment comment { get; set; }
        public Votes votes { get; set; }
        public Assignee assignee { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Issue
    {
        public string expand { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string expand { get; set; }
        public int startAt { get; set; }
        public int maxResults { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public List<Issue> issues { get; set; }
    }

var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var issues = t.issues;
```

Comment: but deserializing to strongly typed object in C# is a far better approach.

Comment: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "GlossDiv". Array position index expected.

Comment: Not able to see images. I have modified my JSON to look good.Could you please modify answer as per this.

Comment: Its sating "var issues" does not exist in current context during debug. not sure way. My "t" is having result.

Comment: `issues` is just a local variable.How come it doesn't exist in the context. we use `var` keyword to implicitly declare local variables.