# How to Deserialize JSON(multi level) in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

My web API is sending this JSON.

```
{   "data":[  
  {  
     "cat_id":"1",
     "category":"Clothing",
     "img_url":"sampleUrl.com"
  },
  {  
     "cat_id":"2",
     "category":"Electronic Shop",
     "img_url":"sampleUrl.com"
  },
  {  
     "cat_id":"3",
     "category":"Grocery",
     "img_url":"sampleUrl.com"
  },
  {  
     "cat_id":"4",
     "category":"Hardware",
     "img_url":"sampleUrl.com"
  }

  ]}
```

I tried to deserialize this JSON using below c# code

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllCategories>>(content);
```

but it throws an exception.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EzyCity.AllCategories]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

AllCategories class

```
 public class AllCategories
{
    private string cat_id;
    private string category;
    private string img_url;

    public string Cat_Id
    {
        get { return cat_id; }
        set { cat_id = value; }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set { category = value; }
    }

    public string Image_Url
    {
        get { return img_url; }
        set { img_url = value; }
    }
}
```

What should be done to deserialize this type of JSON?

Comment: possible answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531441/retrieve-required-string-from-bigger-json-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `json` is a object with an array as the following:

```
public class ObjectData
{
   public List<AllCategories> data{get;set;}
}
```

Therefore you have to desirialize the `Json` into the object:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectData>(content);
```

Answer (score 6):

you need something like this

```
public class Datum
{
    public string cat_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string img_url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

then use

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

to de-serialize

Comment: Upvoted (not only) because you use the correct singularization of "data" :)